# MySQL select distinct value from one table that gives value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables, one with country code and country name and the other with disease and country code. I want to select all the countries that have deaths reported by AIDS from the second table, but print the country name from the first table, not the country code.

So far, I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(country) AS countrydeathbyaids
FROM deaths
WHERE cause = 'AIDS';
```

which gives the correct country codes, but I want to somehow tie in the country table to give country_name rather than country code. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform an `inner join`, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.country_name)
FROM countries c JOIN deaths d ON c.code = d.country
WHERE d.cause = 'AIDS';
```

Assuming `code` is the column name for coutry code.

Comment: that works, but prints duplicates so I added DISTINCT() and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Join it with the countries table:

```
select c.country_name
from countries c
join (
    select distinct country_code
    from deaths
    where cause = 'AIDS'
    ) d on c.country_code = d.country_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, should be able to do a simple join.

Assuming the countries table is named countries and has a name field and a code field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(countries.name) AS countrydeathbyaids
FROM deaths
INNER JOIN countries ON countries.code = deaths.country
WHERE deaths.cause = 'AIDS';
```